# How to stop a program from adding an object that already exists in a file?

Tags: python

```
def Add():
    Name = input('Enter student name:')
    f = open('Stu.txt', 'a')
```

what should I add here to stop the program to add a name that exists in file?

Answer (score 2):

```
def Add():
    name = input('Enter student name:')

    with open('Stu.txt', 'r') as f:
        if name in f.read().split('\n'):
            return
    with open('Stu.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name)
        return
```

This will do if you're just running this once. But if you're adding many names, you may want to read the file's contents into a list at the start, then only add new names to the list if they are not already present, and then write everything to the file at the end. This will save on unnecessary repetitive opening and closing of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary which has names as keys, and then check if your name is already in the dictionary.